# What was the significance of the pentagram?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, an-american-werewolf-in-london

In *An American Werewolf in London*, Jack notices a pentagram on the wall of Slaughtered Lamb. But it was never elaborated what it has to do with the  werewolf and why it made everyone in the pub so silent. Who made that sign or what was it's importance? Was it to indicate voodoo or some other kind of magic involved in the werewolf mystery? Was that ever addressed in any extended media/sequels etc?

Answer (score 7):

The pentagram, especially in the form where it is inscribed inside a circle (a pentacle), is in European folklore a symbol **which repels evil spirits and demons** and protects its wearers. There are a plethora of symbols and rituals which have similar purposes which can be a bit confusing for people from other cultures.

It is also an old belief (which is shared by many cultures) that **once you are talking or even thinking about evil things or draw interest to something to which they belong, you are luring them to the talker** because they feel that someone is talking about them, You know who I am talking about, He who must not be named, right? While the hostile reaction of the pub people is exaggerated (it's a horror movie), superstitious people will be dismissive against people who are in their view challenging fate.

Comment: Voldemort?  Bloody Mary? Hastur?

Comment: @Yasskier shush.....

Comment: Is there some articles or source about this folklore ?

Comment: [You can find some pointers unter *Drude*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude#Drudenfuss). The symbol was very well known in Germany and has still a literary use in *Faustus* when Mephistopheles as devil's envoy is captured by a pentagramm. It has its own name *Drudenfuß* to ward off the Drude. My sources are mostly in German, but you should find plenty information about it as use of an amulet in English if you search for Wicca religion.